# Use a list in two site collection

Tags: 2013

My solution in :
I want have two or more site collection ( for example Human Resource Management and Contract Site) in these site collection I need to have a list ( for example List of Projects). and so use it for lookup or etc! So I want if I update list of Projects in site collection A then I see this update in Site Collection B.

Comment: Something useful: http://www.sharepointfix.com/2010/11/cross-site-collection-dropdown-look-up.html

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to have an **event receiver for each list**.
Firing on the *CRUD event* so you can modify the other lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an item updated event receiver in the siteA list, update the list item in site B programmatically in Site B.

Try the link below:

1. [How to: Create an event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)
2. [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Beside using event receivers and put in your code, you can create a workflow and do it visually using the SharePoint Designer, I don't like the WF option but it is an option. You can consider having this list outside SP as a BCS and use it as external list, you can also use a third party product like Replicator, it will take care of synchronizing the data between site collections as needed without code.

Check these links:

1. [External content types in SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163139%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
2. [Metalogix Replicator](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Replicator/Replicator-for-SharePoint.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross site publishing feature if it's suitable for you reference link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/overview-of-cross-site-publishing

Or you can use SharePoint Content Deployment wizard reference link -  https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spdeploymentwizard